FastAPI background task working as expected locally but when I deploy it in Opensift it runs sequentially
Not able to under why the behaviour is different in openshift.
Service method:
@router.get("/delta")
async def fetch_network_devices_delta(q: str, background_tasks: BackgroundTasks):
    background_tasks.add_task(get_delta_data, q)
    print("after background task completion")
    return {"msg": "running in background"}

Here is my docker file.
FROM python:3.10-slim

WORKDIR /OneApi

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1

COPY requirements.txt /OneApi/requirements.txt
COPY app /OneApi/app
COPY main.py /OneApi/main.py
RUN chmod -R 777 /OneApi/app/assets/fwd_delta
RUN chmod -R 777 /OneApi/

RUN pip3 install --no-cache-dir --upgrade -r requirements.txt

EXPOSE 9999

CMD \["uvicorn", "main:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "9999"\]

I expected it to run the function as background task.

Did you find a solution?
